# Where can I download Visual Studio 2010 merge modules for the MS11-025 security update?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've diagnosed an installation problem to be caused by the lack of the latest VS2010 merge modules (version 10.0.40219.325) on what I believed to be a fully-patched machine. Instead, it has the older version 10.0.40219.1.

It appears that 10.0.40219.325 was introduced as part of a security update: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2565057/en-us

I'm sure I'm missing a really obvious link somewhere, but I can't find where to download an installer for the updated (10.0.40219.325) merge modules (and I'd prefer not to copy them manually from another machine). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As you can tell from the KB link, that update includes updated .msm files.  It is entirely unclear from your question why your installer isn't using them.  Could be as simple as forgetting to rebuild it.

Comment: I am expecting to find updated .msm files in Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules, which is (I believe) where the Visual Studio 2010 installed the merge modules originally. However, the merge modules there are the old (.1) versions. Perhaps I haven't successfully installed the appropriate update, but Windows Update isn't offering it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the download link by searching for "kb2565057 manual installation". It's at
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=27049

[lessmsi](http://lessmsi.activescott.com/) confirms that my merge modules in Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules are now updated. (Hans, thanks for your help. Answering your question somehow helped me find this.)

For what it's worth, I still can't see a link to this download from the [page that I found initially](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2565057/en-us), and my initial searching was for MS11-025 rather than KB2565057. The lesson here for me is probably to use KB numbers when searching microsoft.com.

Comment: Fixes my original installer problem too.